# How much real time was compressed into this 10 second long timelapse Hubble video of Jupiter's aurora?

Tags: observational-astronomy, jupiter, hubble-telescope

The HubbleESA video *Timelapse of Jupiter’s auroras* is discussed in the ESAHubble page [Timelapse of Jupiter’s auroras](https://esahubble.org/videos/heic1613a/) and includes the identifier `heic1613a`. However there's no clear information there about the period of observation.

Note that there is also the page [heic1613 — Photo Release
Hubble captures vivid auroras in Jupiter’s atmosphere](https://esahubble.org/news/heic1613/)

**Question:** How much real time was compressed into this 10 second long timelapse Hubble video of Jupiter's aurora? Were the original images taken over a period of minutes, hours, or days?

I don't notice any breaks, and I think that Jupiter will always be eclipsed by Earth seen from Hubble's low Earth orbit.

Comment: related in Science Advances: [Revealing the source of Jupiter’s x-ray auroral flares](https://advances.sciencemag.org/content/7/28/eabf0851)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the planet is marked with longitudinal lines every 10 degrees, and so you can measure off the video that the planet rotates by about a little less than three longitudinal lines, or about 30 degrees.  As Jupiter has a rotation period of [just under 10 hours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter), the length of time can be estimated as about 10×30/360 hours: 50 minutes, or possibly slightly less.

That is consistent with an observation lasting for half an orbit of Hubble, which has a [95-minute orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble_Space_Telescope).